# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) when trying to iterate over twolists at the same time

Tags: python, list

Can anyone explain what is the problem with this code?

```
for game_name,game_size in games_names,games_sizes:
    print(f'Game_Name = {game_name} Size = {game_size}')
```

This is Python code where I try to iterate over two lists and print their values but it gives me this error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Hi, please, use markdown for your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate over 2 lists in same moment, you should use `zip()` funciton.

Example:

```py
>>> lol = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> kek = [6,7,8,9,10]
>>> for num, secnum in zip(lol, kek):
...     print(num, secnum)
```

Let me explain why you can't "unpack" it.
For example, lets say that we have this list:
`arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. On every iteration you can get only 1 object, right?

```py
one = arr[0]
two = arr[2]
...
```

So that's how we could get values from list.
We can assign values like this too:

```py
one, two, three = arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]
```

In python there is `*` sign, means that you could 'pack' value in list.

```py
colors = ['cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'black']
cyan, magenta, *other = colors

print(cyan)
print(magenta)
print(other)
```

Output:

```py
cyan
magenta
['yellow', 'black']
```

Summary what unpucking do:

1. Unpacking assigns elements of the list to multiple variables.
2. Use the asterisk (*) in front of a variable like this *variable_name to pack the leftover elements of a list into another list.